# I am having a problem gradle build. Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

> Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

After adding a module to my project I started getting this error message. I have tried looking it up online but the suggestions have not fixed it.

Here are my buildscript and plugins.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried this but it did not work

```
buildscript {
    ext {

        kotlinVersion = "1.5.1"
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use compose 1.2.0 instead?

Comment: And where is a reference to `kotlinVersion`?

Comment: Try to migrate to compose compiler 1.2.0 and kotlin 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Change ext.kotlinVersion to 1.7.20. I had this issue last week and this did it for me.

```
ext {
   kotlinVersion = "1.7.20"
}
```